# Cannot enable SSL on my website in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, ssl

I am currently hosting 4 different websites on my Ubuntu 18.04 PC with no problem. A problem appears only when I enable or try to enable SSL. I followed this simplest tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Bo78eDEy7g to do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt install python-certbot-apache
certbot --apache -d peytuk.com
```

You can go ahead and see https://peytuk.com is not responding.

I have tried to manually install the certificate before, and failed there as well. I certainly am not an expert on this, so please go easy on me.

Just in case if my ufw status is needed

```
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
20/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include the full output of the commands you used. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: According to terminal i have successfully enabled https://peytuk.com. Can this have something related to rubbish certificates i tried to generate before? Outputs of commands are quite normal. I would've shared errors if there was any..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same issue, don't forget to forward port 443 on your router [just changed port 80 to 443 :P].